# Sharing Cookies and Sessions between Renderer and Main Process in Electron

Tags: session, authentication, cookies, electron, desktop

When creating an Electron Desktop application, that performs Basic Authentication for the user, we load up a BrowswerWindow, and load a login form. This form, when submitted, essentially performs a POST to URL to authenticate and authorize the user for more privileged information. If the authentication was a success, the user's session is set so that future requests in the BrowserWindow use the user's authenticated session.

However, I haven't seen a case where the session in the renderer process (BrowserWindow) can be stored to the Main Process, so that if the main process needs to make a request, it can use the same authenticated session. How can I allow the main process share the session and cookies that the Renderer process used for any requests that it needs to make?

TL;DR: User successfully logs in in the BrowserWindow in Electron. How do I make requests in the main process after the user is authenticated, with the same session as the session in the BrowserWindow?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:[sessions](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/session)
You can share data between browserWindow and main.js with the IPC module: [IPC Tutorial](https://coursetro.com/posts/code/122/Electron-IPC-Tutorial---Communication-within-your-Electron-App)

Answer (score 0):

The Electron renderer process uses the Chromium request pipeline.
The Electron main process uses the node.js request pipeline.

Apart from the issue you raise with cookies/sessions, node.js HTTPS requests from the main process will not work on corporate networks where a custom root certificate is installed in the Windows certificate store.

The simplest way to get around this is to run all your requests through the renderer process. [`electron-remote`](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-remote#the-remote-ajax-module) has some code to simplify this:

```
import { requireTaskPool } from 'electron-remote';

const remoteAjax = requireTaskPool(require.resolve('electron-remote/remote-ajax'));

// Result is the object that XmlHttpRequest gives you
let result = await remoteAjax.get('https://httpbin.org/get');
console.log(result.url)

>>> 'https://httpbin.org/get'
```